# PHP and XML attributes follow up

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing, simplexml

how can i get the attribute values for seconds using php:

```
<yt:duration seconds='12445'/>
```

this is what i have done so far:

```
        $xmlstr  = file_get_contents($xml);
    $xml_content = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlstr); 
    echo $xml_content->xpath('//yt:duration')->attributes;
    print_r($xml_content->xpath('//yt:duration'));
    echo $xml_content->xpath('//yt:duration')->attributes()->seconds;
```

which displays these messages:

```
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\ytm\xmlTest.php on line 22
Array ( [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes] => Array ( [seconds] => 12445 ) ) ) 
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\ytm\xmlTest.php on line 24

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\ytm\xmlTest.php on line 24
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This:

```
$xml_content->xpath('//yt:duration')
```

Returns an array (as your `print_r()` will tell you). You'll have to grab the first element (at index 0) in order to work with the SimpleXMLElement that corresponds to the `<yt:duration>` node:

```
$list = $xml_content->xpath('//yt:duration');
$node = $list[0];
```

Then, you can get the attibutes with `attributes()`:

```
$attributes = $node->attributes();
echo $attributes['seconds']; // Not 100% sure on this, might be $attributes->seconds
```